# Fetching contact by uri doesn't work

Tags: android

I've created intent to pick contact like this:

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, HELPER.PICK_CONTACT);
```

Then process results this way:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == HELPER.PICK_CONTACT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactUri = data.getData();

                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);

                    c.moveToFirst()
                    ...
```

In above mentioned code, `c.moveToFirst()` results *false* after selecting a contact.
The application has

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

in its manifest.

Has anybody have an idea how to get contact's data after selecting contact? Please help.

Comment: you are compiling against API 23 or Android 6.0?

Comment: I'm compiling against API 23

Comment: so have you get runtime permission?

Comment: If you mean phone asking for permissions after code tries to fetch contacts then nothing like this happened. But in phone's settings, its written that application has permissions for reading contacts.

Comment: what is android OS version of your cell?

Comment: It's Android 5.0.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115482/discussion-between-marek-and-sohail-zahid).

Comment: One of the things I've done is unisnstalling app from phone, and then running it once more - seems to work.